# store timestamp of an action in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a query here :

```html
alter proc  spbadge
  @WeekNumber nvarchar(255)
 as
 begin

 update pointsbadge
 set 
 
     badge1 =(case when WeeklyHoursLogged >= '40' then 1 else 0 end),
    badge2 = (case when WeeklyHoursLogged<'40' then 1 else 0 end),
    badge3 = (case WHEN WeeklyHoursLogged >= 50 and WeeklyHoursLogged < 55 THEN '1' else 0 end),
    badge4 = (case WHEN WeeklyHoursLogged >= 55 and WeeklyHoursLogged < 60 THEN '1' else 0 end),
   badge5 = (case WHEN WeeklyHoursLogged >= 60  THEN '1' else 0 end);

end
```

Now,after running the above query with the conditions,I have this updated "pointsBadge" table -

[image: imm]

**Scenario :**
Here you will see 5 badges (badge1 till badge5). When any employee is rewarded a badge it becomes 1, else 0. For example: Brinda wins all the badges, whereas lyka wins only badge1.

**Problem** : I want to have an another table "employee_badge" - where whenever any employee is rewarded a badge ,i.e whenever her value is 1,in this "employee_badge" table ,the employeeid,badgeid and the time gets recorded.

For instance like this,
[image: badgetime]

I am storing the image and ID of the badges in a different table like this : 
[image: ii]

How do you guys think this can be achieved.can I modify the above stored procedure or you suggest a better efficient solution for this .I believe I need to use an update trigger here.But ,how will I use it on the above stored procedure.

Comment: What is`WeeklyHoursLogged`?

Comment: That is a part of the condition on the basis of which a badge is rewarded.My problem here is different.Anyways,thanks.God bless.

Comment: I suggest to create `employee_badge` table.

Comment: You can create TRIGGER on pointsBadge and get updated employee_id, with the help of employee id get the badgeid and insert into  employee_badge. --GETDATE() for timestamp

Comment: @Suraz thanks for the input.Your solution looks perfect and efficient.Will you be kind enough to help me with the query.I am struggling with it. God bless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out with the following code, if it satisfies your requirement: you can adjust query according to your table structure and data

--Badge Point Information

```
CREATE TABLE pointsBadge(EmployeeName VARCHAR(50), EmployeeID INT, badge1 INT, badge2 INT, badge3 INT, badge4 INT, badge5 INT)
INSERT INTO pointsBadge VALUES 
('Lyka', 1122, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
('Brinda', 2233, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
('Anil', 34, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

--New table to store badge data employee wise with current timestamp

```
CREATE TABLE employee_badge(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), employee_id INT, badge_id INT, earned_on DATETIME)
```

--Badge Information Table

```
CREATE TABLE #badges(BadgeId INT IDENTITY(1, 1), BadgeName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #badges VALUES 
('Badge1'),
('Badge2'),
('Badge3'),
('Badge4'),
('Badge5'),
('Badge6')
```

--Trigger to insert data into employee_badge table with updated data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[TRGUpdate_badge_info]', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER dbo.TRGUpdate_badge_info
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRGUpdate_badge_info ON dbo.pointsBadge
FOR UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO employee_badge
    SELECT d.EmployeeID,
            b.BadgeId,
            GETDATE()
    FROM pointsBadge p
    INNER JOIN DELETED d ON p.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN #badges b ON b.BadgeName = CASE WHEN (p.badge1 <> d.badge1) THEN 'Badge1'
                                                WHEN (p.badge2 <> d.badge2) THEN 'Badge2'
                                                WHEN (p.badge3 <> d.badge3) THEN 'Badge3'
                                                WHEN (p.badge4 <> d.badge4) THEN 'Badge4'
                                                WHEN (p.badge5 <> d.badge5) THEN 'Badge5' 
                                           END
GO

UPDATE pointsBadge SET badge5 = 2 WHERE employeeID = 1122

SELECT * FROM employee_badge
```

Comment: Thank you so much... you are a Genius.God bless. @Suraz